# PHP: How to str_replace a html string, but not within certain tags

Tags: replace

I have a string, like this:

```
<p>Ple ple ple BLA xo xo xo <span class="tooltip-content"><span class="tooltip-text">uuu BLA pla</span></span> he he he ha ha ha.</p>
```

How can i str_replace a word **BLA** but not the one(s) within **span.tooltip-content** ? Only the one(s) from "outside" the span tag.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but fastest solution that come to my mind is:

1. remove everything from $string between "<span class..." and closing tag using strpos function

then

2. str_replace ("bla", "with something", $string);

Comment: And that would be fine, but how do I "store" the removed part and put it back to the string? I may have more then one occurance of the`<span class...>` tag.